# How can I use two radio buttons in header of a gridview to select all corresponding record in the same column having same radio button?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, radio-button

How can I use two radio buttons in header of a grid view to select all corresponding record in the same column having same radio button?

Here is my code:

```
 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Page">
     <HeaderTemplate>
         <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton1" runat="server" Text="Select All Colour" />
         <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton2" runat="server" Text="Select All B/W" />                                
     </HeaderTemplate>
     <ItemTemplate>                                
         <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton3" runat="server" Text="Colour" />
         <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton4" runat="server" Text="B/W" />
     </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: Do you want help in the code behind file?

Comment: Yes Mr. Praveen. As i select a radio button in header than that will also make selection to the itemtemplet of same radio button.